# Ubuntu(14.04 64bit) slows down after 24 hours

Tags: 14.10

My system runs like a dream when I start up the pc but becomes unusable by the end of the day.

This also happens to me by the end of the day too.

[image]

I will look at the system monitor and nothing is being maxed out when it starts to slow down.

All I know is at the start of the day apps will open right away and run like a dream and by the end they can take a min to open and are sluggish.

I can fix it with a restart but it's becoming a pain.

hardware

Cpu= Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Quad CPU    Q9400  @ 2.66GHz

Ram =4gb ddr2

500gb hdd

gpu=amd 5870

Comment: Can you please edit your question to give a hardware list?

Comment: Honestly I think a hardware list should be required for every question, and maybe answers too.

Comment: i added some hardware info. if there is any thing you need me to add and all add it.

Comment: Very strange... Please give the output of the terminal command `free -m` when it's slow like this.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/dzoU0l8.png

Comment: And that's when it's slow?

Comment: I've got the same issue, so I'll keep track here. Here's my `free -hm` http://i.imgur.com/XSk9d1J.png This usually happens about 5 hours into the work day, and system monitor doesn't show anything being maxed out.

Comment: yes that's when its slow.